# How to convert principal components of a $2\times2$ covariance matrix into principal components of a correlation matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, covariance

All,

I am wondering if there is any way to mathematically express the change in direction of the principal components from the $2\times2$ covariance matrix to the correlation matrix. In other words, if $$\Sigma=(X-\bar X)^T(X-\bar X)/(n-1)$$
$$=~
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma^2_{1}  & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_{2} \end{array} \right) $$
and
$$\lambda,e$$
are the eigen vector pairs of $\Sigma$
then $$Y_{\Sigma}= e^TX$$
are the principal components. Can these be re-expressed for the correlation matrix $$\rho=~
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  & \rho_{12} \\
\rho_{12} & 1\end{array} \right) $$
in terms of the covariance matrix in this manner: $$Y_{\rho}= f(Y_{\Sigma})$$